# Clang compilation error: "variable 'array' with variably modified type cannot be captured in lambda expression

Tags: c++11, lambda, g++, clang

In the code listed below, "LambdaTest" fails with the following error on Clang only:

```
shared/LambdaTest.cpp:8:31: error: variable 'array' with variably 
modified type cannot be captured in a lambda expression
    auto myLambdaFunction = [&array]()
                          ^
shared/LambdaTest.cpp:7:9: note: 'array' declared here
    int array[length];
```

The function "LambdaTest2" which passes the array as a parameter instead of capturing compiles fine on G++/Clang.

```
// Compiles with G++ but fails in Clang
void LambdaTest(int length)
{
    int array[length];
    auto myLambdaFunction = [&array]()
    {
        array[0] = 2;
    };
    myLambdaFunction();
}

// Compiles OK with G++ and Clang
void LambdaTest2(int length)
{
    int array[length];
    auto myLambdaFunction = [](int* myarray)
    {
        myarray[0] = 2;
    };
    myLambdaFunction(array);
}
```

Two questions:

1. What does the compiler error message "variable 'array' with variably modified type cannot be captured in a lambda expression" mean?
2. Why does LambdaTest fail to compile on Clang and not G++?

Thanks in advance.

COMPILER VERSIONS:
   *G++ version 4.6.3
   *clang version 3.5.0.210790

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int array[length];` is not allowed in Standard C++.  The dimension of an array must be known at compile-time.

What you are seeing is typical for non-standard features: they conflict with standard features at some point.  The reason this isn't standard is because nobody has been able to make a satisfactory proposal that resolves those conflicts.  Instead, each compiler has done their own thing.

You will have to either stop using the non-standard feature, or live with what a compiler happens to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

VLA (Variable-length array) is not officially supported in C++.
You can instead use `std::vector` like so:

```
void LambdaTest(int length)
{
    std::vector<int> array(length);
    auto myLambdaFunction = [&array]()
    {
        array[0] = 2;
    };
    myLambdaFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both answers above for pointing out that VLAs are non-standard. Now I know what to search for.

Here are more are related links to the subject.

[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

[Why no VLAS in C++](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/2bfe25800d4961e8/9545494bbb336dfa)